# What is the default watermark in fixed windowing?

Tags: streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am reading the article [the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-102](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-102) by Tyler Akidau. For the watermark I am still a bit confused, i.e. about the code in the article:

```
PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> scores = input
  .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(2)))
               .triggering(AtWatermark()))

  .apply(Sum.integersPerKey());
```

It simply tells the engine trigger at the watermark, but how does the engine know the watermark ? As I understand it should be some kind of time delay user needs to say. Or is the engine built so smart that it tries to make one (according some default strategy or configuration) for the users ?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Dataflow (which is what Tyler Akidau is describing in the article you cite) can use a heuristic to estimate watermarks -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234263/2000823) for more details.

Flink, on the other hand, depends on explicit watermarks which are either [emitted by the data source](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#source-functions-with-timestamps-and-watermarks) or by a [watermark generator](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#timestamp-assigners--watermark-generators). The most common approach is to assume a bounded delay.

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer is quite helpful.